# How to get only gps location using sencha touch?

Tags: android, gps, sencha-touch-2

I have created sencha touch application and i want to try get the current location of android device using below code.

```
Ext.create('Ext.util.Geolocation',  
autoUpdate: true,  
allowHighAccuracy: true,  
listeners: {  
locationupdate: function(geo) {  
    latitude=geo.position.coords.latitude;  
    longitude=geo.position.coords.longitude;  
    if(Global.currentUserPositionMarker)  
    {  
        latlng1=new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);  
        currentPosMarker.setPosition(latlng1);  
    }  
   }  
  }  
});
```

In my device the gps icon will be blinking but Couldn't get the current location of device gps position.
It always get current location from my network provider.
I want frequently update current location from the device gps possition.
Like the google map app for android the gps icon is always stable, i want to like that in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start your Device WI-FI and then try to load your app.
Because It will work for me to get the current location from gps.
I have face the same problem to get the current location from gps.
I am also add question for releated these problem [See The Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227147/android-can-i-set-first-priority-to-gps-to-get-current-location-in-google-map).

Answer (score 2):

Add **Frequency** parameter in GeoLocation object.

```
Ext.create('Ext.util.Geolocation',  
autoUpdate: true,
frequency:1000,  
allowHighAccuracy: true,  
listeners: {  
locationupdate: function(geo) {  
    latitude=geo.position.coords.latitude;  
    longitude=geo.position.coords.longitude;  
    if(Global.currentUserPositionMarker)  
    {  
        latlng1=new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);  
        currentPosMarker.setPosition(latlng1);  
    }  
   }  
 }  
});
```

**Frequency** value is in milliseconds and it is used to update Geo location by given time.

Comment: I use frequency parameter in geolocaion also i give the frequency:1 but till my icon was blinking very fast.